# Jsoup - extracting variable value

Tags: java, html, html-parsing

I am parsing the html from the following [webpage](http://www.canadacomputers.com/product_info.php?item_id=041120) using Jsoup. How do I get the value from the variable *price_ourBase*:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var price_ourBase = 279;
    .
    .
    .
</script>
```

JS:

```
Element upperContainer_inner = document.select("div.upperContainer_inner").first();
Element table = upperContainer_inner.select("table.645.0.left.0.0").first();
Element script = table.select("script").first();
Element base_ourPrice = script.select("base_ourPrice").first();
price = (?, not sure what to put here or if there is more code needed).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think jSoup can parse javascript like that. But, you could select the contents of the script with jSoup and then you could do something like

```
String[] result = script.toString().split(" ");
if(result[1].equals("price_ourBase"))
        System.out.println("Our price is "+result[3].split(";")[0]);
```